# How to detect selected Media is Time-Lapse, Slow-Motion or .mp4

Tags: ios, swift4, video-processing, gpuimage, avasset

Creating an application for image and video processing, where app requirement is set device Orientation according to selected video content orientation from the gallery. So I have used some line of code to get selected media current orientation kindly check Below code for orientation get from selected content.

```
var video_orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    guard let transform = tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first?.preferredTransform else {
        return .portrait
    }
    switch (transform.tx, transform.ty) {
    case (0, 0):
        return .landscapeLeft
    case (videoFirstFrameSize.width, videoFirstFrameSize.height):
        return .landscapeRight
    case (0, videoFirstFrameSize.width):
        return .portraitUpsideDown
    default:
        return .portrait
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when user select video (slow-Mo, Normal) from Gallery its working fine.
But when user select Time-Lapse video from gallery orientation going to changed, I have done too many research related to get orientation also have create many experiment and then finally I got some solution, and the solution is if we selected Time-lapse we need to pass `AVMediaType.timecode` in video type but now the problem is, how should I set it on selected assets.
Any help is really appreciable and will save my life :P but its going little frustrating.

**NOTE:- `var video_orientation` Is the Extension property of `AVAssets`**

Comment: For SloMo you can check below link :https://stackoverflow.com/a/42109206/2058242

Comment: https://medium.com/@xcadaverx/avfoundation-cmtimemapping-c3521d4da6b1

Comment: hi @Md.IbrahimHassan thanks for answer and  i agreed with  your suggestion, theoretically it is good to understand  but practically  can you please suggest some line of code..

Comment: I was actually trying to work on this issue but I had used UIImagePickerViewController I will try it using PHAssets and let you know. BTW its a very interesting question.

Comment: Please and thanks in advance for your efforts

Comment: @Sumitsingh you should work on frame rate it might helps you.

Comment: @RB1509 thanks for the idea I was working on this R&D from last 3 weeks but did't get the perfect solution.

Comment: you need to work with timerange and framerate. if possible than share you research code i will definitely helps you.

Comment: please check this link and set / get FPS of video. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52473333/9137841

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code how you can detect media type easily.

```
enum AssetType {
    case photo
    case video
    case livePhoto
    case sloMo
    case timeLapse
    case burst
    case gif
}

func getMediaType(asset : PHAsset)-> AssetType? {
        if asset.mediaType == .image {
            if asset.representsBurst {
                return .burst
            } else if asset.playbackStyle == .imageAnimated {
                return .gif
            } else if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.image && ((asset.mediaSubtypes.rawValue & PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoLive.rawValue) != 0)) {
                return .livePhoto
            } else {
                return .photo
            }
        } else if asset.mediaType == .video {
            if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.video && ((asset.mediaSubtypes.rawValue & PHAssetMediaSubtype.videoTimelapse.rawValue) != 0)) {
                return .timeLapse
            } else if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaType.video && ((asset.mediaSubtypes.rawValue & PHAssetMediaSubtype.videoHighFrameRate.rawValue) != 0)) {
                return .sloMo
            } else {
                return .video
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```